# react-hook-form onSubmit is not working after applying redux-persist

Tags: redux-toolkit, react-hook-form, redux-persist

I'm making wizard form with react-hook-form and redux tookit.
And now I'm trying to apply redux-persist to keep the form's values after refreshing or clicking to go back.

But handleSubmit is not working after I set redux-toolkit.
There's no error in console, so I'd like to know what is wrong.

Here are my codes.

**store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { formReducer } from './features/formSlice';
import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storageSession,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, formReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: [thunk],
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './i18n';
import { store, persistor } from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**programName.js (step 1 in my wizard form)**

```
function ProgramName() {
  const programName = useSelector((state) => state.programName);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: programName,
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleOnSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(Object.values(data));
    dispatch(submitStep1(Object.values(data)));
    history.push('./step2');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleOnSubmit)}>
      <Text size={30} weight={800} mb={10}>
        Step 1. Program name
      </Text>
      <label htmlFor="programName">
        Program Name
        <input
          name="programName"
          {...register('programName', { required: 'fill out!' })}
        />
        <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="programName" as="p" />
      </label>
      <Button type="submit">next</Button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default ProgramName;
```

**formSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const formSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'form',
  initialState: {
    programName: '',
    targetName: '',
    category: [],
    tags: [],
    targetLocation: '',
    rewardType: '',
    rewardAmount: '',
  },
  reducers: {
    submitStep1: (state, action) => {
      state.programName = action.payload;
    }, //etc..

export const formReducer = formSlice.reducer;

export const {
  submitStep1,
  submitStep2,
  submitStep3,
  submitStep4,
  submitStep5,
  submitStep6,
  submitStep7,
  submitStep8,
} = formSlice.actions;
```

**more detail example**
[image]

when I click the next, handleSubmit is not working and the error message is showing underneath though I fill the input, so I cannot be into step 2 form.

Comment: can you please share your error image for better understanding.

Comment: I've added and please check it out!

Comment: console.log(Object.values(data)) ??? what does this show??

Comment: const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  keyPrefix: 'redux-',
  whitelist: [],
};

Comment: it works! but if I modify the input value after I click to go back, it doesn't work..

Comment: also some fields values are not persisted. I don't know why..

Comment: can you please check your react-router version because you use history.push('./step2'); I think if you have a route like step2 then it can be like this history.push('/step2'); if your router v6 then use useNavigate. and also please share your action function submitStep1().

Comment: I'm using router v5 and have added action function code. please check.